# Showing that a function solves a second-order differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

[image: Taken from Braun, M. - Differential Equations and their Applications]

I found this problem in a differential equations' textbook, but I cannot get rid of the integral sign in the second function and I can't tell if it is indeed a solution to the given equation. Also, because of the same reason, I can't tell if the Wronskian is always non-zero in the given domain. Is there a trick to solve this problem without actually solving the integral explicitly? I know it can be written in terms of the $erfi(x)$ function but it isn't mentioned in the text, so there must be a way to avoid using it.

Comment: Put the your so called solution into the differential equation, if RHS turns out  to be equal to LHS, then it is **a** solution to that ODE.

Comment: What is $W[y_1,y_2](t)$?

Comment: @zoli I'm pretty sure that's the Wronskian

Comment: @zoli it is the Wronskian of these two solutions. Specifically, $W(t) = {x_1}(t){{\dot x}_2}(t) - {x_2}(t){{\dot x}_1}(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 
$$
e^{t^2/2}y(t)=\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds
$$
you get via differentiation and fundamental theorem
$$
e^{t^2/2}=(e^{t^2/2}y(t))'=e^{t^2/2}(y'(t)+ty(t))
$$
so that
$$
y'(t)+ty(t)=1\implies y''(t)+ty'(t)+y(t)=0
$$

---

With $y_2=y_1v$ you get for the Wronskian
$$
W[y_1,y_2]
=\det\pmatrix{y_1&y_1v\\y_1'&y_1'v+y_1v'}
=\det\pmatrix{y_1&0\\y_1'&y_1v'}=y_1^2v'
$$
the middle step by subtracting $v$ times the first column from the second.

Comment: The first part of your answer is elegant and clear, thank you very much! However, I don't get why the second entry from the first row vanishes.

Comment: You multiply the first column with $v$ and subtract from the second. This is a valid determinant operation that leaves the value of the determinant unchanged. Basic linear algebra.

Comment: Sorry! I completely forgot about that rule for determinants. I understand now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: upon further reflection, aren't column operations (i.e. add a scalar multiple of column a to column b) only valid for ... scalars? since $v$ is a function of $t$, the column operation you used would result in different Wronskians for distinct values of $t$.

Comment: No, this is just operating on the function values at a fixed time $t$ that are entries in the matrix, these are just scalars.